# QGIS dynamic filtering parent and child features

Tags: qgis, query, filtering

I have in QGIS 3.22 point layer, I'm trying to visualize the table:

| fid | point_name | parent_relation_to_fid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | point-X | 1 |
| 2 | point-Y | 1 |
| 3 | point-X | 2 |
| 4 | point-Z | 3 |
| 5 | point-Y | 3 |
| 6 | point-X | 2 |
| 7 | point-Z | 4 |

I want to filter in Query builder from the table all features equal to point_name "point-X" value and `parent_relation_to_fid` of those features corresponding to "point-X" relation.
I want this algorithm to be dynamic because there are thousands of point features in the table and manual filtering is time consuming. But as an example the manual result would have been:

```
point_name = 'point-X' AND
parent_relation_to_fid = '1' OR
parent_relation_to_fid = '2'
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic expression would look like this:

```
(point_name = 'point-X') AND (parent_relation_to_fid = '1' OR parent_relation_to_fid = '2')
```